# RegExp in PHP not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I've got a problem and I don't know how to fix it. I wan't to parse the emoticons of the comments and I'm trying with RegExp but not getting anything:

Tried with this expression:

> (?<=\s|^)[<:-}]+(?=\s|$)

and got a blank message, anything showing. Tried at http://regexr.com/ and it throws an error in the lookbehind part.

Then I found this one:

> ~\b[<:-}]+\b~

and it's not working (but at least shows the message without converting the emojis to image and adding a dot before the last letter: x.D ^_.^ ...)

My code is something like this:

```
$smiles = array(
        'xD'    => 'laugh.png',
        '>:)'   => 'laugh.png',
        'x('    => 'angry.png',
        ':(('   => 'cry.png',
        ':*'    => 'kiss.png',
        ':))'   => 'laugh.png',
        ':D'    => 'laugh.png',
        ':-D'   => 'laugh.png',
        ':x'    => 'love.png',
        '<3'    => 'love.png',
        '(:|'   => 'sleepy.png',
        ':)'    => 'smile.png',
        ':-)'   => 'smile.png',
        ':('    => 'sad.png',
        ':-('   => 'sad.png',
        ';)'    => 'wink.png',
        ';-)'   => 'wink.png',
        '^_^'   => 'wink.png',
        '^^'    => 'wink.png',
    );



    if($this->smiles) {
         foreach($smiles as $icon=>$image) {
              $icon = preg_quote($icon);
              $parsedMessage = preg_replace("~\b".$icon."\b~",$image,$parsedMessage);
         }
    }
```

Any idea ? :S All I want to do is to parse them and avoiding to parse when links for example or things like that.

Greetings!

Comment: `$parsedMessage = str_replace(array_keys($smiles), $smiles, $parsedMessage);`

Comment: Word boundaries `\b` only make sense if there is a neighboring alphanumeric character.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that makes no sense because if it finds it inside a link it will work wrongly.

mario Then how am I supposed to make it work?

Comment: @mario then which expression should I use?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ( actually 1.5 ) issues:

- (minor/spurious) The hyphen `-` in your test regexp and several of the `$smiles` keys marks a character range,which may not be what you want;
- (severe) `preg_quote($icon)` escapes all characters with special semantics in a regex but it does not add the brackets and the repetition operator of the character class.

Comment: Im not really into regexp and just wanted it to make that little script... I dont get what youre trying to explain me, sorry.. Could you make it more explanative or with any examples of the issues there? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, used this at the end:

```
$parsedMessage = preg_replace("/(?<=\s|^)([:;=<_)(xX]{1})+(([:-_]{1}|[3]|[()]{1}){1})(?=\s|$)/",
                  "<img src='".$this->url."/".$CONF['theme_url']."/images/icons/emoticons/".$image."' height='14' width='14' />",$parsedMessage);
```